# Getting started with Rest-Assured for REST-Api Testing

Tags: automated-testing, java, api-testing, rest

I am new to REST-Api testing. i am getting started with Rest-Assured for Rest-Api testing. i am having an issue in my first ever testcase.

The code is as follows:

```
@Test
public void testGetSingleUser() {
      expect().
        statusCode(200).
        body(
          "email", equals("test@hascode.com"),
          "firstName", equals("Tim"),
          "lastName", equals("Testerman"),
          "id", equals("1")).
        when().
        get("/service/single-user");
}
```

In this code the `expect().` command is not working. I need to fix this issue quickly and move on.

Comment: I made a short example for RestAssured http://olyv-qa.blogspot.com/2017/07/restassured-short-example.html. For status code I used dedicated method `expectStatusCode()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You have to import the `RestAssured` class incl. method as static.

`import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.expect;`

Or you call the method on this way:

`RestAssured.expect()`

**Useful Links**

- [Java Doc](http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.3.1/apidocs/com/jayway/restassured/RestAssured.html)
- [Getting started](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: equalsTo() is not working. equals() in working fine. The problem is that my expect() command is not working. I am using eclipse with rest-assured jar included.

Comment: @JarreeArhamShahid Can you put the exception into your question, to be more specific? Thank you.

Comment: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method expect() is undefined for the type RestTest

Comment: This is the failure trace. Its not working because the expect() in the code above has an error. Do i need to include any jars to make it work?

Comment: @JarreeArhamShahid Updated the answer.